# All combination possibilities

Tags: python, list, combinations

I repost with a simplified question (my previous post was closed).

I need to output all combination of a list of length `N`.

I already know that `combinations` will do this with, as example, the actual input list: `['A, 'B']` ==> `output: ['A', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'B']`

**But** I need this: `['A', 'A'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'A'], ['B', 'B']`.

Is there a way to do it with `combinations()`?

Comment: This looks like a [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to me.

Comment: `list(itertools.product('AB', repeat=2)) # [('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B')]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Comment: Wasn't your previous question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/464864/11301900? What's different about this one?

Answer (score 3):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is the tool for the job

```
>>> list(itertools.product('AB', repeat=2))
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
all_combinations = [[x,y] for x in list_length_N for y in list_length_N]
```

Example with N=2

```
list_2 = [0,1]
all_combinations = [[x,y] for x in list_2 for y in list_2]
print(all_combinations)
```

Output:

```
[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```